# Get rid of undocking tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I have been searching online and I cannot find out a way to do this.

The way it's so easy to 'undock' the tabs in Firefox is really frustrating (I am using a drawing tablet and for whatever reason it is very easy to undock tabs using this tool). Is there a way to disable the 'undocking' feature?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bug489729-disable-detach-and-t/); it was updated recently to work in newer versions of Firefox (4.0 and up). Install the add-on, check the box to "Disable detach tab", and you should not have to worry about tearing off tabs with Firefox on your tablet.